# Android java.lang.VerifyError: com/company/project/Main

Tags: java, android

I am absolutely defeated by this issue, I saw some similar questions but none were of any help.  I cannot seem to run an application that I as running just fine a few days ago.

I am getting the dreaded, VerifyError and was hoping that someone might be able to figure out where I am going wrong.

**Here is a screen shots of my project build path**

*Libraries*

[image]

*Order and Export*

[image]

**Here is my complete stack trace**

```
03-20 00:01:07.176: E/AndroidRuntime(13968): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 00:01:07.176: E/AndroidRuntime(13968): java.lang.VerifyError: com/snrblabs/bishop/Main
03-20 00:01:07.176: E/AndroidRuntime(13968):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-20 00:01:07.176: E/AndroidRuntime(13968):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
03-20 00:01:07.176: E/AndroidRuntime(13968):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
03-20 00:01:07.176: E/AndroidRuntime(13968):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
03-20 00:01:07.176: E/AndroidRuntime(13968):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-20 00:01:07.176: E/AndroidRuntime(13968):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-20 00:01:07.176: E/AndroidRuntime(13968):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-20 00:01:07.176: E/AndroidRuntime(13968):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-20 00:01:07.176: E/AndroidRuntime(13968):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-20 00:01:07.176: E/AndroidRuntime(13968):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-20 00:01:07.176: E/AndroidRuntime(13968):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 00:01:07.176: E/AndroidRuntime(13968):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-20 00:01:07.176: E/AndroidRuntime(13968):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-20 00:01:07.176: E/AndroidRuntime(13968):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-20 00:01:07.176: E/AndroidRuntime(13968):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**And here is my classpath**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Sources/Third Party Libraries/dom4j-1.6.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Sources/Third Party Libraries/google-voice-java-1.10-java6.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Sources/Third Party Libraries/jaxen-1.1.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Sources/Third Party Libraries/json.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Sources/Third Party Libraries/jtidy.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

**EDIT**

So the issue appears to occur because I am trying to upgrade the google-voice-java library,

when I reverted to an older build with the older library I was just fine.  However when I tried to add the newest google-voice-java library I received the same error.

***And yes I cleaned and build my project***

Comment: Have you cleaned and rebuilt your project?

Comment: Why don't you keep all the library files into your project's libs directory and then add it into the build path of your project ?

Comment: I have cleaned and rebuilt my project, I usually keep the library files in the libs directory this was current configuration was a result of utter frustration

Comment: any solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The named class file is invalid. Recompile it. Clean and rebuild everything.

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps you, put your all requires `jar` `files` in `libs` folder , if there are no libs folder in your project create  it and put here all jar files and again select this all files from libs in your project path, make clean your project and build again.